# Enterprise Integration Specialist Certification discontinued?

Tags: spring, certificate, spring-integration

I am considering to take the Enterprise Integration Specialist Certification exam but was unable to find it in the official Pivotal/Vmware sites. Any idea if this certificate has been discontinued?

Thanks in advance.